# how to create a dynamic php url

Tags: php, wordpress, url

I am trying to create a dynamic url that looks like this `localhost/wordpress/slug/username`

I am using the `wp_redirect` function to redirect the user to this url but the probleme is that i don't know how to write this url ?

I've tried to create a variable like so `$user = wp_get_current_user();`to includ it like so  `wp_redirect( 'http://localhost/wordpress/slug/$user' );`but it doesn't work so please someone help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you need to use double quotes for variable interpolation.

```
"http://localhost/wordpress/slug/$user"
```

Second the $user variable yields a WP_User object, you actually want the display_name property

```
$user->display_name
```

So the final code looks like this:

```
wp_redirect( "http://localhost/wordpress/slug/$user->display_name" );
```

Comment: hello and thanks for your the answer but with the code you gave me i on ly obtain this result when click the link  [http://localhost/wordpress/slug] , so now i think theres a probleme with declaring the variable or maybe i'm missing to declare a function  ,,,, keep in mind that i'm writing my code in the function.php file in my theme folder

Comment: please tell me what to do next

Comment: comon dude help me plz